# JavaFx Chart dependecy Maven?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to generate a chart using JavaFx Chart Librairie. In Oracle documentaion https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/line-chart.htm#CIHGBCFI an example How to generate different charts.

I don't know which librairie I have to add to my pom.xml in my maven Project.

I added this dependency but I get some Compiler error:

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>javafx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-ui-charts</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Can someOne please guides me How to use JavaFx Chart libeairie.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class LineChartSample extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Line Chart Sample");
        //defining the axes
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Number of Month");
        //creating the chart
        final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart = 
                new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);

        lineChart.setTitle("Stock Monitoring, 2010");
        //defining a series
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("My portfolio");
        //populating the series with data
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 23));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 14));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 15));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 24));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 34));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 36));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7, 22));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 45));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 43));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 17));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(11, 29));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 25));

        Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart,800,600);
        lineChart.getData().add(series);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? AFAIK charts are bundled with JFX, so you shouldn't need any extra dependencies...

Comment: I'm using Java 8. How Can I add JavaFx to my Maven Project.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Could solve it using this dependency from : https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.openjfx/javafx-controls/11/source-code/javafx/scene/chart/LineChart.java

Here is what has been added to my pom.xml make JavaFX works in the "project" section :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>MyClass</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>11-ea+24</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>11</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```